# How to display a list one by one using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, effect

I want to display / hide a list one by one using JQuery, here is my code:
The list:

```
<p>This is the text</p>
<p>This is the text 1</p>
<p>This is the text 2</p>
```

The button function:

```
$("#hide").on("click", function(event) {
hideList($("p"), 0);
});
```

Here is the function that will hide/display the list:

```
function hideList(list, index) {
    if (index < list.length) {
        list.eq(index).toggle(2000, hideList(list, index+1));
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

But when the button clicked, the 3 `<p>` are hide together, not one by one. But such code works, the `<p>` displayed one by one:

```
$("#show").on("click", function(event) {
    $("p").eq(0).toggle(2000, function() {
        $("p").eq(1).toggle(2000, function() {
            $("p").eq(2).toggle(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Does anyone know what caused the issue? thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference as the complete callback to `toggle`, in your case you were calling the function and passing the value returned by `hideList` - `undefied` as the callback

```
function hideList(list, index) {
    if (index < list.length) {
        list.eq(index).toggle(2000, function(){
            hideList(list, index+1)
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AJPD4/)

Answer (score 0):

Arun's answer is correct but why not just continue to use jquery. Use the delay and queue.

```
function hideList(list){
 $(list).each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).delay(2000*index).queue(
            function(n){
                $(this).toggle()
                n();
            })
    })
}
```